# How to trigger back all database changes after failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have seen many appointment Scheduling applications in rails. The user select a pre configured slot like (9:00 am - 10:00 am) for appointment and the slot is blocked for further appointments. How the slot is made available again in between if a failure occur? Is there a way to trigger all changes back.? Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the queries in `transaction` block

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  # your queries
end
```

It will rollback previous queries in case of a failure/error.

More info here - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: where should i add the transaction block???

Comment: Wherever you put the logic to block the slots, go through the link to docs to understand it better.